# how to make query show the an other column of the primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

umm I'm not sure I've made the title right but its kind of hard to express it in short words.

I have to tables

**table1:**

```
id  |  name    
1   |  alice    
2   | bob
```

**table 2:**

```
user_id | date
  2     | 2014-11-1    
  2     | 2014-11-2    
  1     | 2014-11-3
```

as a query, if I want to show `table 2` but instead of the integer numbers of `user_id`, I want it to show the corresponding names of the users where this info is stored in `table 1`.

I think this is supposed to be easy but I don't know how to get this done.

Comment: use a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: `SELECT table1.name, table2.date from table2 INNER JOIN table1 on table2.user_id = table1.id` Should get get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query along the lines of -

```
select t1.name, t2.date
from table_1 t1 inner join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT t2.user_id, t1.name
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON   t1.id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
SELECT
        `b`.`name`,
        `a`.`date`
FROM 
         table2 a
         INNER JOIN table1 b ON (a.user_id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    B.[Name]
   ,A.[date]
FROM [table 2] A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [table1] B
      ON A.[user_id] = B.[id]
```